Как пишется слово "допы"?
Имеются в виду дополнительные занятия.

допы - это сленг, а не аббревиатура, так и пишется. И  только мн.ч. Можно в кавычки взять "допы", тогда точно никто не придерётся.

@Буратино  Почему только мн.ч.? Например, доп – дополнительный товар.

Fleurdellyss, Ваш вопрос непонятен. Как написали, так и пишется. Как можно по-другому написать? Дапы, добы, допи?

"Допы": где логика? Мнение личное, непопулярное. Взгляд родителя-музыканта     https://dzen.ru/a/Y-8-XdSznj1qQAuR

https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=допы&mode=spravka&simple=0  № 256360
Как пишется сокращение "доп(*)соглашение" от слов дополнительное соглашение?
ОТВЕТ
Возможно: доп. соглашение (доп. — графическое сокращение прилагательного дополнительный) и допсоглашение (как сложносокращенное слово). //  № 264434
В статье, посвященной топ-менеджерам в России, слово «топ-менеджеры» неоднократно заменяется словом «топы». Нужно ли брать слово «топы» в кавычки или допустимо  без кавычек: «зарплата топов…», «многие топы участвуют в…»?
ОТВЕТ
Предпочтительно заключить это слово в кавычки.

Это я писала про топы,  для сравнения.  Топ есть в словаре, в отличие от допа. Также в сложных словах пишется дефис.   Если про персонал, то лучше в кавычках (такого значения нет).  Все познается в сравнении  (Рене Декарт).

@АлександрСтрелец, не понимаю, к чему пояснения: я спрашиваю про заглавные буквы, как во многих аббревиатурах

Fleurdellyss, ну тогда так бы и спросили, потому что о заглавных буквах даже не подумаешь. Не пишут же: ГЕН - генеральный, ПРОД - продовольственный и т. д.


Нормировано только доп. соглашение, доп. занятие и т.д.

Я знала, нормальные люди не любят читать пьесы, но мне нравилось, что... действие мчится вперед, вся необходимая доп. информация умещается в коротких ремарках.
Остальное – практика использования.

К сожалению, часто пишут без точки:

– И во сколько мне обойдётся эта доп услуга? – не удерживаюсь от укола. Амалия Март, (Не)настоящий парень, 2022
В школе деньги смешные платили, поэтому я ещё доп занятия вела и курсовые с рефератами писала. Дарья Фиалкова, История одного долга, 2021
Хотя вообще-то могла бы и предложить оплатить доп прокат.
Мария Быховская, Петля, 2022
И возьми доп батарею.
Андрей Истомин, Первый дозор, 2020
В этом случае стоит поработать, чтобы продать больше доп опций. Константин Монэ, Секрет больших продаж в автосалоне.

Форма мн. числа допы используется преимущественно и обычно без кавычек, но кавычки возможны (от текста зависит).

У нас ещё допы по ботанике.
Джулия Кертисс, 30 Дней, 2023
– Пять на два, выходные отдельно оплачиваются, если хозяину допы нужны. Зарплата высокая. Умела бы готовить, сама бы уволилась и пошла.
– Я договорился, – сказал он, закуривая, и сплюнул под ноги. – Барыга… У человека горе, а он свои допы втюхивает.
Сергей Валерьевич Мельников, Мы будем гореть в аду вместе, 2022

А это карты (спец. термин)

Так что эта карта при ответе на данный вопрос будет требовать допа.
Иван Фьюс, Первый учебник Таро. На основе колоды Райдера – Уэйта
Карта слов
Статья
